# Losing styles when create a PDF from a .docx with Apache POI and Pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi

The code creates a .docx and then creates a PDF from it. When open, the margins and styles do not match the .docx, but the main problem is that the text has moved and some images are missed. The code that cretes the PDF:

```
    InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(new File(sourcePath + name));
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc);

    PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.getDefault();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationPath + name.replace("." + MimeUtil2.getExtension(name), "") + ".pdf"));
    PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
```

About missed images I have no clue, with margins I have tried to add them adding the following code between instantiating the document and creating PdfOptions:

```
    CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
    CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
    pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
    pageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(1440L));
    pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
    pageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(1440L));
```

But do not work.

I found a way to modify the margins: adding the same code above in the creation of the .docx, where it seems to work. But that does not fix the problem of the missed image and moved texts. Also it makes the code uglier and does not feel right because the styles are added correctly after (in the writing of the .docx).

How can i keep the styles from the .docx or adding them to make the *PDF* the closest to the .docx?

Java 1.8 , Apache POI 3.15 and Pdfbox 2.0.9 .

Comment: Your question is not about iText. Tag removed.

Comment: I don't see how this is about PDFBox, there is no PDFBox code there. PdfConverter is from POI (or does it use PDFBox under the hood?).

Comment: You are right, I use PDFBox but later, print the fist PDF to merge multiple PDFs in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution but only works on Windows(probably easy to convert to use in Linux, but I didn't research it). My problem was the .docx didn't looks exactly like the printed PDF. I used [OfficeToPDF](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/PDF/OfficeToPDF.shtml) and called it with java. The command line is like this:

```
[path-to-officetopdf]/officetopdf.exe [source]\myFile.docx [destination]\myNewPDF.pdf
```

To anyone who may concern, this is how you execute a shell command with java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public static String executeShellCommand(String command) {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

}
```

I hope this can help someone, if I found the way to make it with Linux I will post it.